# Using the binomial-tree approach to price an option in quantlib - with time expressed as a fraction of year

Tags: quantlib

For learning purpose, I'm trying to price, with [quantlib](http://quantlib.org/index.shtml), an European option using the *Cox-Ross-Rubinstein tree approach*.

Some examples are provided in the file `EquityOption.cpp` that is part of the library.

However I would like to price it, **without** using dates (that is to say, without any day convention, calendar, expiration date ...) but using *only* a fraction of year as maturity  (ex : with `T = 0.5` ).

> As far I read, all examples only consider the case with dates
>   expressed as "real" dates (ex : 11/01/2016) and not expressed as time
>   to maturity (ex: T= 0.1), i.e. the standard textbook case.

Since the library relies heavily on engines, and that those engines are mainly designed with dates, I have some difficulties to get rid off the dates.

For the BS analytical formula, it is easy since the core of the engine relies on the [BlackScholesCalculator](http://quantlib.org/reference/class_quant_lib_1_1_black_scholes_calculator.html) that is dates independent (see a  [full example here](https://mhittesdorf.wordpress.com/2013/07/29/introducing-quantlib-black-scholes-and-the-greeks/)) .

However for the binomial case, there is no such date-independent routine (no BinomialCalculator..),  and the `DiscretizedVanillaOption` class requires an engine's variable as input to instantiate it..

One plausible solution that came to my mind is to find two "fakes" dates, by playing with a pseudo `.yearFraction(FakeStartDate, FakeEndDate);` function to find two optimal dates that match the fraction I want. Then to use these two dates to compute the price. However this strategy seems quiet cumbersome for a such simple request.

How can I compute the value of an option using the binomial approach with a maturity expressed as a fraction of year in quantlib ?

Please see below what I have done so far, I'm stuck to the line that instantiate the `DiscretizedVanillaOption`.

```
    Calendar calendar      = NullCalendar();             
    DayCounter dayCounter  = SimpleDayCounter();
    Date t0(1);     
    Option::Type type = Option::Put;
    Real S0 = spot_;
    Real K = strike_;
    Spread q =  dividendYield_;
    Rate r = interestRate_;
    Volatility sigma = volatility_;

    Settings::instance().evaluationDate() = t0;
    Handle<Quote> underlyingH((boost::static_pointer_cast<Quote>(boost::make_shared<SimpleQuote>(S0))));
    Handle<YieldTermStructure> flatDividendTS((boost::static_pointer_cast<YieldTermStructure>(boost::make_shared<FlatForward>(t0, q, dayCounter))));
    Handle<YieldTermStructure> flatTermStructure((boost::static_pointer_cast<YieldTermStructure>(boost::make_shared<FlatForward>(t0, r, dayCounter))));
    Handle<BlackVolTermStructure> flatVolTS((boost::static_pointer_cast<BlackVolTermStructure>(boost::make_shared<BlackConstantVol>(t0, calendar, sigma, dayCounter))));
    boost::shared_ptr<BlackScholesMertonProcess> bsmProcess(new BlackScholesMertonProcess(underlyingH, flatDividendTS, flatTermStructure, flatVolTS));
    boost::shared_ptr<StrikedTypePayoff> payoff(new PlainVanillaPayoff(type, K));

    Size timeSteps_ = 200;
    Time maturity = 0.2;
    TimeGrid grid(maturity, timeSteps_);    
    boost::shared_ptr<CoxRossRubinstein> tree(new CoxRossRubinstein(bsmProcess, maturity, timeSteps_,  payoff->strike()));
    boost::shared_ptr<BlackScholesLattice<CoxRossRubinstein> > lattice( new BlackScholesLattice<CoxRossRubinstein>(tree, r, maturity, timeSteps_));

    DiscretizedVanillaOption option(/* ????*/,bsmProcess, grid);//<--------- First argument Here ?

    option.initialize(lattice, maturity);
    double price = option.presentValue();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, thanks to Luigi's answer and by observing the examples in the `testsuite` I have been able to achieve it. The fake starting date is setted to today's date and the exercise date as follow :

```
 Date exDate = today + Integer(timeToMaturity_*360+0.5);
```

See below a working example for pricing an american option with CRR :

```
double American_CoxRossRubinstein_T(bool IsCall /*if false= put*/,
                                    double underlying_,
                                    double strike_,
                                    double riskfree_,
                                    double volatility_,
                                    double dividendYield_,
                                    double timeToMaturity_)
{
    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    Option::Type optionType =IsCall ? Option::Call : Option::Put ;
    QuantLib::Date today = QuantLib::Date::todaysDate();
    QuantLib::Settings::instance().evaluationDate() = today;
    QuantLib::DayCounter dayCounter = QuantLib::Actual360();
    Calendar calendar  = NullCalendar(); 
    Date exDate = today + Integer(timeToMaturity_*360+0.5);
    Handle<Quote> underlyingH((boost::static_pointer_cast<Quote>(boost::make_shared<SimpleQuote>(underlying_))));
    Handle<YieldTermStructure> flatDividendTS((boost::static_pointer_cast<YieldTermStructure>(boost::make_shared<FlatForward>(today, dividendYield_, dayCounter))));
    Handle<YieldTermStructure> flatTermStructure((boost::static_pointer_cast<YieldTermStructure>(boost::make_shared<FlatForward>(today,riskfree_, dayCounter))));
    Handle<BlackVolTermStructure> flatVolTS((boost::static_pointer_cast<BlackVolTermStructure>(boost::make_shared<BlackConstantVol>(today, calendar, volatility_, dayCounter))));
    boost::shared_ptr<Exercise> americanExercise(new AmericanExercise(today, exDate));
    boost::shared_ptr<StrikedTypePayoff> payoff(new PlainVanillaPayoff(optionType, strike_));
    VanillaOption americanOption(payoff, americanExercise);
    boost::shared_ptr<BlackScholesMertonProcess> bsmProcess(new BlackScholesMertonProcess(underlyingH, flatDividendTS, flatTermStructure, flatVolTS));
    Size timeSteps = static_cast<int>(std::max(700 * timeToMaturity_, 20.0));
    americanOption.setPricingEngine(boost::static_pointer_cast<PricingEngine>(boost::make_shared<BinomialVanillaEngine<CoxRossRubinstein>>(bsmProcess, timeSteps )));
    Real OptionPrice = americanOption.NPV();
    std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << "American_CoxRossRubinstein_T = " << OptionPrice << std::endl;
    return OptionPrice;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid you'll have to use fake dates, as you mentioned.

To make the process less cumbersome, you can use a day counter with a simple formula such as Act/360.  Given a start date, it will make it easier to determine the corresponding end date (`startDate+36` for T=0.1, `startDate+180` for T=0.5 and so on) without having to play with candidates.

Comment: Thanks, however this implies a maximum precision of 1/360 whereas the theoretical model does not impose it.

Comment: Yes and no.  The dates actually adjust to the nodes of the passed `TimeGrid` instance before calculation, so you should be good.  (You can look at the implementation of the `DiscretizedVanillaOption` constructor for details.)